# Pandas - How to convert an string column into Integer... then convert into String with 10 charact

Tags: python, pandas

I'm performing a data analysis where one of the steps is to create a key by combining several fields.

Unfortunally, the number of digits in a given field is not always the same.

###### Some information

- Datatype of `my_field` is `object`;
- `nan` values have been replaced by the `'-'` character.
- But, basically, the `my_field` is numbers (INTEGER) formatted in Text.

###### Code

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data ={'product': ['PA1', 'PA2', 'PA3', 'PA4', 'PA5', 'PA6', 'PA7', 'PA8'],
       'my_field': ['001', '0000000000002', '3', '04', '-', '5', '-', '6']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)   
df
```

###### Raw Data

|  | product | my_field |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | PA1 | 001 |
| 1 | PA2 | 0000000000002 |
| 2 | PA3 | 3 |
| 3 | PA4 | 04 |
| 4 | PA5 | - |
| 5 | PA6 | 5 |
| 6 | PA7 | - |
| 7 | PA8 | 6 |

###### My Aproach:

```py
df['my_field'] = np.where(df['my_field'] == '-', '-' , df['my_field'].str.zfill(10) )
df
```

###### My Output:

|  | product | my_field |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | PA1 | 0000000001 |
| 1 | PA2 | 0000000000002 |
| 2 | PA3 | 0000000003 |
| 3 | PA4 | 0000000004 |
| 4 | PA5 | - |
| 5 | PA6 | 0000000005 |
| 6 | PA7 | - |
| 7 | PA8 | 0000000006 |

###### Desired Output:

|  | product | my_field |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | PA1 | 0000000001 |
| 1 | PA2 | 0000000002 |
| 2 | PA3 | 0000000003 |
| 3 | PA4 | 0000000004 |
| 4 | PA5 | - |
| 5 | PA6 | 0000000005 |
| 6 | PA7 | - |
| 7 | PA8 | 0000000006 |

The problem: Some outputs get more then 10 char.

Comment: Perhaps you want the zfill inside the parenthesis of your where statement `np.where(df['my_field'] == '-', '-' , df['my_field'].str.zfill(10))`

Comment: @Chris I edited the post syntax.  Sorry... It was a typo mistake.  Thanks, but it´s not the problem.

Comment: @Chris That´s why i want to convert into INT then Object.

Comment: could you use Python's `len` function to check the length and then prepend leading zeros?

Comment: @AudioBaton I prefer not!  Cause of the rules of dataset.  I prefer doing somethind like ```df.my_filed.int().str().zfill(10)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about slicing after `zfill`, this way you'll keep the last 10 characters only:

```
df['my_field'] = np.where(df['my_field'] == '-', '-', df['my_field'].str.zfill(10).str[-10:])
```

Alternative with boolean indexing:

```
df.loc[df['my_field'] != '-',
       'my_field'] = df['my_field'].str.zfill(10).str[-10:]
```

Output:

```
  product    my_field
0     PA1  0000000001
1     PA2  0000000002
2     PA3  0000000003
3     PA4  0000000004
4     PA5           -
5     PA6  0000000005
6     PA7           -
7     PA8  0000000006
```

Comment: I think it´s an possible aproach  mr. @mozway I will check on the real data.   Also give me your feedback of my question quality please.  I am trying to improve myself.  Thanks.

Comment: The question is quite clear, I upvoted it. I would just remove the step 2 of "What I Really Want", this is not an end goal but your vision of how the problem should be solved and not a necessary step in my opinion ;)

Comment: Done..  post edited

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution using len():

```
def myfield_format(x):
    if len(x)>10:
        field=str(x)[(len(str(x))-10):] if x!='-' else '-'
    else:
        field=(10-len(str(x)))*'0'+str(x) if x!='-' else '-'
        
    return field

df['my_field']=df['my_field'].map(lambda x: myfield_format(x))
```

| product | my_field |
| --- | --- |
| PA1 | 0000000001 |
| PA2 | 0000000002 |
| PA3 | 0000000003 |
| PA4 | 0000000004 |
| PA5 | - |
| PA6 | 0000000005 |
| PA7 | - |
| PA8 | 0000000006 |

Comment: Do not work....

Answer (score 0):

```
df.assign(my_field=df.my_field.map(lambda x:str(int(x)).zfill(10) if x.isdigit() else x))
```

out

```
 product    my_field
0     PA1  0000000001
1     PA2  0000000002
2     PA3  0000000003
3     PA4  0000000004
4     PA5           -
5     PA6  0000000005
6     PA7           -
7     PA8  0000000006
```